# Pass values using annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I am trying to create an annotation and pass a variable as parameter to the impl method. Below is my code to create an annotation.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = Loggable1Impl.class)
public @interface Loggable1 {
    String message() default "Invalid userId";
}
```

Below is my impl class

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class Loggable1Impl implements ConstraintValidator<Loggable, String> {
    
    public void initialize(Loggable contactNumber) {
    }

    public boolean isValid(String generatedUserId, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        System.out.println("generatedUserId in Loggable1 :: " + generatedUserId);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am trying to use it in a spring-boot application

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@PostMapping("/api1/{user}")
public Topic regiterUser(@PathVariable String user ) {
    String generatedUserId = user + "1";
    return generatedUserId ;
}
```

I want to pass `generatedUserId` to my annotaion `Loggable1`

Please assist

Comment: Values used in annotations must be compile-time constants. They cannot be dynamically created at runtime, that doesn't make any sense. Seems your question comes from a fundamental misunderstanding of what kind of problems annotations are designed to solve.

Comment: Are you trying to validate the value of `genereatedUserId`?

Comment: @Daly yes, you are right, I want to pass that value

Comment: Validation annotations do not work by passing the value in, rather the annotation is applied to the line above the variable definition and java passes it automatically. While you could do something like that in this case, it would be pretty hacky and hard to understand. I would suggest just having a private method to validate and log `generatedUserId`. That will be easier to read and implement.